SwiftUI - Tappable views overlayed on an image
I'm working on a text-recognition app that

allows a user to select a pdf
converts that pdf to an image
performs text recognition
shows the image with bounding boxes around words that are tappable to select for future actions

I have everything working except for the boxes receiving taps.  Not sure if it's because they are in an overlay, but I need the size of the rendered image to determine placement of the word boxes (see normalize method -- text recognition returns a bounding box based on the size of the image) so not sure of another way to implement it.  I've tried adding .allowsHitTesting = false to the overlay itself, thinking it was capturing the tap, but that didn't help.
Code is below, removing some elements for brevity.
import SwiftUI
import Vision

struct StatementWordsImageView: View {
    @State private var importing = false
    @State var image: NSImage?
    @State var words: [WordGroup] = []
    
    @State var size: CGSize = CGSize()
    
    var body: some View {
        VStack {
            Button("Import") {
                importing = true
            }
            .fileImporter(
                isPresented: $importing,
                allowedContentTypes: [.pdf]
            ) { result in
                switch result {
                case .success(let file):
                    processStatement(url: file.absoluteURL)
                case .failure(let error):
                    print(error.localizedDescription)
                }
            }
            
            ZStack {
                if let processedImage = image {
                    Image(nsImage: processedImage)
                        .resizable()
                        .aspectRatio(contentMode: .fit)
                        .overlay {
                            GeometryReader { geo in
                                Color.clear
                                    .border(.blue)
                                    .onAppear {
                                        size = geo.size
                                        
                                    }
                                addWords
                            }
                        }
                } else {
                    Text("No statement loaded")
                }
            }
        }
    }
    
    func normalize(rectangle: CGRect, basedOn: CGSize) -> CGRect {
        let width = basedOn.width
        let height = basedOn.height
        
        let x = rectangle.minX * width
        let y = rectangle.maxY * height
        let rectWidth = rectangle.width * width
        let rectHeight = rectangle.height * height
        
        return CGRect(x: x, y: y, width: rectWidth, height: rectHeight)
    }
    
    private var addWords: some View {
        ZStack {
            if !self.words.isEmpty {
                let firstGroup = self.words.first!
                let firstWord = firstGroup.words.first!
                let rectangle = normalize(rectangle: firstWord.box, basedOn: self.size)
                
                Rectangle()
                    .fill(.red)
                    .onTapGesture {
                        print("Tapped")
                    }
            }
        }
    }
    
    func processStatement(url: URL) {
        guard let pdfImage = PDFUtilities.drawPDFfromURL(url: url, writeToDisk: false) else {
            print("Could not convert PDF to image")
            return
        }
        
        recognizeText(image: pdfImage) { w in
            words = w
        }
        self.image = pdfImage
    }

    //lengthy function replaced with sample code
    func recognizeText(image: NSImage, completion: @escaping([WordGroup]) -> Void) {
        var groupsOfWords: [WordGroup] = []
        
        var words: [Word] = []
        words.append(Word(text: "Test", box: CGRect(x: 0.5, y: 0.5, width: 30.0, height: 10.0)))
        groupsOfWords.append(WordGroup(words: words))
        
        completion(groupsOfWords)
    }
}

struct WordGroup {
    var words: [Word]
}

struct Word {
    var text: String
    var box: CGRect
}

